# How to load view in CodeIgniter from the controller function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have Controller Class "User" with this function:

```
public function add_form(){

        $this->load->view('insert');
    }
```

Here *insert* it is insert.php view file with some form that I want to dysplay when I click on a some link in another file. This link looks like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/user/add_form">Insert New User</a>
```

But it not work in this way. If I click on the link it shoud switch me to class User on function add_form, and this function shoud load view 'insert' but it's display that Page Not Found. Please help me )

Answer (score 0):

It was misprint in class name, sorry.